# PHP mail() does not work from a particular file

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I have a page that charges for a purchase and I want to send an email to admin on success. So when the condition is true (the charge was successful), I call the function mail(). In the code below, see under if ($subscription) {} (Yes, this conditional is working properly). However, it never works. If I put the mail function in a separate file all by itself, it works fine. It returns true and I get the email. It just won't work from the file I am working on. Very mysterious! I've been over everything many times and I can't see anything that would conflict with the mail() function.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
//set_error_handler("var_dump");
session_start();

if ( ( isset($_SESSION['signup_token']) ) AND ( $_POST['token'] == 
$_SESSION['signup_token'] ) ) {
// Start Charging

include_once 'classes/index.php';
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");

// Set the stripe plan
switch ( $_POST['plan'] ) {
    case 'Basic Hosting':
        $plan = 'plan_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
        break;
    case 'Business Hosting':
        $plan = 'plan_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
        break;
    case 'Pro Hosting':
        $plan = 'plan_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
        break;
    case "Discount Hosting":
        $plan = 'something';
        break;
    case 'New Website';
        $plan = 'New Website';
        break;
}

$pin = mt_rand('100000', '999999');

try {

    // Create the Stripe customer
    $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create([
        'email' => $_POST['email'],
        //'description' => $_POST['first_name'] . ' ' . $_POST['last_name'],
        'metadata' => array(
            'Purchased from' => 'example.com',
            'Name' => $_POST['name'],
            'Support PIN' => $pin,
        ),
        'source'  => $_POST['stripeToken'],
    ]);

    // Subscribe the customer to the selected plan
    $subscription = \Stripe\Subscription::create([
        'customer' => $customer->id,
        'items' => [['plan' => $plan]],
    ]);

    if ( $subscription ) {
        $to = "something@gmail.com";
        $subject = "New subscription to";
        $txt = "<strong>Customer Name:</strong> <br />";
        $txt .= "<strong>Customer Email:</strong> <br />";
        $txt .= "<strong>Support PIN:</strong> ";
        $headers = "From: store@example.com" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

        if (mail( $to, $subject, $txt, $headers ) ) {
            echo "<p>Email to admin sent</p>";
        };
        include 'purchase_success.php';
    }

    if ( $plan == 'New Website') {
        include 'includes/new_website_email.php';
        //include 'includes/new_subscription_email.php';
    }

} catch (Exception $e) {

    error_log("unable to sign up customer:" . $_POST['stripeEmail'].
    ", error:" . $e->getMessage());
    $error = $e->getMessage();

}

// End Charging
} else {

    echo "Why are you here?";

}
```

Comment: Try some troubleshooting/logging along the way. You give the email sending code, but you don't show where it is in relation to the first set of code.

Comment: Try to debug the code row by row.

Comment: Its included under if ( $subscription )

Comment: Edited the question to clarify the issue.

Comment: I suggest you try to get the error message returned by the mail function so as to aid you troubleshooting. You can use this code to get the error message:
 $errorMessage = error_get_last()['message'];

Comment: Thanks - no output from error_get_last. I'm assuming that would go right after the mail() use.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything wrong with this code. I put my application on different server and it worked fine. Since this is in dev I'll just use the other server. Maybe this can serve as an example for someone. When all else fails with mail(), it might be the server!